# If you see some movies in the Apple TV website, does that mean you can watch it if you join some program?

Tags: appletv

For example, this page shows [the movie Parasite on Apple TV](https://tv.apple.com/us/movie/parasite/umc.cmc.5j8t2blurpxgpnxeqtm15n8i1).  Does that mean if you join some program, such as Apple TV+, then you can watch it as included in the program?

Apple TV+ is said to be included one year free if you buy some new Apple devices, so does that include the movies as listed on Apple TV?

Answer (score 4):

> Does that mean if you join some program, such as Apple TV+, then you can watch it as included in the program?

**Nope**.

> Apple TV+ is said to be included one year free if you buy some new Apple devices, so does that include the movies as listed on Apple TV?

Apple TV+ is Apple's original programming service. The Apple TV+ subscription only lets you watch the original Apple programming for free, which is made available under the service, and **not** any other media available on the Apple TV app. They have to be purchased/rented separately.

Apple TV app on macOS and iOS/iPadOS now consolidates the iTunes store movies selection, along with Apple TV+, Apple's original programming service.

Starting with macOS Catalina and iOS/iPadOS 13, the iTunes app on macOS which used to let users purchased or rent movies has now been discontinued, and replaced with independent Music, TV and Podcasts apps. Read this Apple Support article to learn more:

- [What happened to iTunes?](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT210200)

Apple's TV app for macOS is now one stop place to cater to all the visual media consumption available for sale/rent from Apple (which used to be previously made available via iTunes macOS app).

Apple TV+ is a subscription based, original programming service from Apple. A user's enrolment into the service doesn't mean they'll be able to watch any movie made available by Apple for sale/rent for free. So for your case, although the said movie is available on Apple TV, you'd need to pay for it to purchase/rent.

(**P.S.**: It could be argued that Apple marketing may not have done a good job with making user aware with all the changes that have happened here. The new changes have the potential of leaving a lot of users confused. Here's an interesting take on the same by [Daring Fireball](https://daringfireball.net/linked/2019/11/05/curtis-apple-tv), one of the most widely regarded Apple blogger).

Comment: Also worth noting that there is a difference between the webpages for regular iTunes programs and Apple TV+ programs. Take [The Morning Show](https://tv.apple.com/us/show/the-morning-show/umc.cmc.25tn3v8ku4b39tr6ccgb8nl6m?l=en) for example, the logo at the top turns to the Apple TV+ logo, and the button changes to `Try Apple TV+ Free` instead of `View in iTunes` on the Parasite page. Makes it easier to work out if it's included or not if you're not sure whether it's an Apple-produced program or not.

Comment: so if the movie Parasite is showing in Apple TV webpage, what does it mean to watch this movie? That it really belongs to iTunes on a Mac and the new TV app on iPad and I have to either rent or buy the movie?

Comment: @nonopolarity It apparently implies that the movie is available to "watch" on the Apple TV app, without disclosing the means.

Comment: ok I have an iPad with the "TV app", and I searched for it and found it. It is $14.99 to buy and $3.99 to rent... so looks like it is like iTunes. Interesting fact it, it showed the related movie Housemaid, and I clicked and click the actress "Jeon Do-yeon" and found the movie "A Man and a Woman", and it actually showed available to watch on Amazon Prime Video...

Comment: @nonopolarity, yes Apple TV (the app) will connect to other services to let you know what's available. It means that if you start watching a TV series on Prime Video for example, it will display in Apple TV for you to continue watching the next episode. This will then open up Prime Video and automatically start playing the episode for you, acting as a hub for all of your viewing needs. I'm not sure what other services it links to in the US, as I'm based in the UK, but I know Netflix does _not_ show in the Apple TV app.